# What's the name for the logical operator that does nothing?

Tags: boolean-logic

When I list all boolean operators over one variable, I
find one operator which does nothing:

```
A f(A)
0 0
1 1
```

Does this operator f have an official name?

Bye

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about symbolic logic, not programming.


Comment: @Wooble What do you think programming is, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is traditionally called [identity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

Comment: Here somebody says "no inversion": http://users.senet.com.au/~dwsmith/Concepts/ExORfig1.gif

Comment: Oh well, apparently circuit designers have their own name for it. You are free to invent another name for it ;-)